# Salesforce as an identity provider issue

Tags: identity

I want to implement Salesforce as an identity provider. so I have according to deployment guide as below:

1. Register Salesforce account
2. Login Salesforce operation panel
3. Setup -> Domain Management -> My Domain -> Apply for new domain -> Successful -> Deploy to Users -> Done

The deployment description that can find "**Setup -> Security Controls -> Identity provider**" item from Setup list, But I can't found this item... even if I used keyword "identity provider" in search bar will not found it.

[image: Panel diagram]

Q. How can i used "identity provider" item in operation panel? or How to insert "identity provider" item in operation list?

Please help me to solve this issue, Thanks.

Comment: What is your org edition ?Is it enterprise or below that ?

Comment: just a update Identity provider is Available in: Developer, Enterprise, Performance, Unlimited, and Database.com Editions only

Comment: Current I used to trial 30 days version. I want to used this version that can doing feasibility evaluate. But the trial version seem can't do. Really appreciate Mohith and Himanshu help.